# Number of sub-triangles of Divided Equilateral Triangles(DET).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, hypothesis-testing

Exercise on *Mathematical Induction* is from **Mathematics for Computer Science** by Albert R. Meyer, Eric Lehman, and Frank Thomson Leighton.

1. *Divided Equilateral Triangles* (DETs) can be built as follows:
   $\bullet$ A single equilateral triangle counts as a DET whose only subtriangle is itself.
   $\bullet$ If $T::= \bigtriangleup$ is a DET, then the equilateral triangle $T'$ built out of 4 copies of $T$ as shown below is also a DET, and the subtriangles of $T'$ are exactly the subtriangles of each of the copies of $T$.

[image]

> Define the length of a DET to be the number of subtriangles with an edge on its base. Prove **by induction on length** that the total number of subtriangles of a DET is the square of its length.

Above all, I've noticed that **the length of DET doubles  each time**. However, I can't go further, namely, can't find the way to write induction hypothesis. Please help me to determine induction hypothesis and skeleton of proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DET is an element of the sequence $$T_1,T_2,T_3, ... .$$
where each $T_{n+1}=T_n'$ and $T_1=T$.

The inductive hypothesis is that the number of subtriangles of $T_n$ is the square of its length. This is clearly true for $T_1$.

Suppose the hypothesis to be true for $n=k$.

$T_{k+1}$ is four copies of $T_k$ and so...

> its length is twice the length, $l$ say, of $T_k$ and its number of subtriangles is four times the number of subtriangles, $A$ say, of $T_k$. We know that $A=l^2$ and therefore $4A=(2l)^2$.

> The hypothesis is therefore true for $k+1$ and so, by induction, is true for all positive integers $n$.