# a DET with one of its corner sub-triangles missing can tiled with trapezoids made of 3 triangles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025244/number-of-sub-triangles-of-divided-equilateral-trianglesdet) post, I've described what is **DET**. The following question is also about **DET** and induction

> Show that a DET with one of its corner sub-triangles removed can be tiles with trapezoids built out of three equilateral triangles.

My proof:

Let induction hypothesis $P(n)$ be "a triangle cut into $4^n$ equilateral triangles and one corner missing can tiled with trapezoids made up of 3 standard equilateral triangles"

Base case $(n=1)$: A triangle made of $4$ triangles with one corner missing is exactly a trapezoid made of $3$ triangles.

Inductive step: Assume that a tiling exists for a triangle of size $4^n$. Show that a tiling exists for a triangle of size $4^{n+1}$. For a triangle with $4^{n+1}$ equilateral triangles, consider it to be made of $4$ larger triangles, each $4$ times the area.

I want to continue like this: Take the $3$ adjacent corner sub-triangles from each of $3$ triangles of size $4^n$. You can replace these $3$ sub-triangles with $1$ trapezoid, clearly, and, by induction hypothesis, tile these $3$ triangles with trapezoids consisting of 3 sub-triangles. There left $1$ triangle of size $4^n$. Since one of corner sub-triangles must be removed, by induction hypothesis, this can be done. We're done. a triangle of size $4^{n+1}$ with one of its corner sub-triangles removed is tiled with trapezoids made of $3$ triangles. 
We can conclude by induction principle that $\forall n \geq 1: P(n)$ holds. $\blacksquare$

Is this part Ok? I think it can expressed better than this, but can't find a way to do it. I appreciate your answers.

**NOTES:** all triangles are equilateral triangles and trapezoids are made of 3 standard (standard means 1) equilateral triangles.

Comment: did you get the solution of this question